# How to solve this limit of a function?

Tags: limits, functions, trigonometry

So I'm having trouble with the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{x\sin x}{1-\cos2x}}$$

Tried to solve it multiple times and failed, so i posted it here...
If possible, solve it in steps, so I can see what you've done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{x \sin x}{1 - \cos 2x} = \frac{x \sin x}{2 \sin ^2 x} = \frac{1/2}{(\sin x)/x}$. So required limit $= \frac{1/2}{\lim_{x \to 0} (\sin x)/x} = \frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $\dfrac{x\sin x}{1-\cos 2x}=\dfrac{x\sin x}{2\sin^2 x}$.

Answer (score 1):

Use L'Hospital rules. Preferably more than once.